# In case of Error, program shows unexpected behavior

Tags: java, try-catch

I was just trying something with try-catch and this code:

```
public class MainThread
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            badMethod();  
            System.out.print("A"); 
        }  
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            System.out.print("B");  
        } 
        finally 
        {
            System.out.print("C"); 
        } 
        System.out.print("D"); 
    }  
    public static void badMethod() 
    {
        throw new Error(); /* Line 22 */
    } 
}
```

I understand `Error` will not be caught by the `catch` block above, but the `finally` block will be executed, and then the JVM will terminate.

But when I try to run the program many times, I get different outputs:

`C` printed before the stack trace:

```
CException in thread "main" java.lang.Error
  at MainThread.badMethod(MainThread.java:22)
  at MainThread.main(MainThread.java:7)
```

or `C` printed after the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error
  at MainThread.badMethod(MainThread.java:22)
  at MainThread.main(MainThread.java:7)
C
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `System.out` stream and the `System.err` stream are separate streams which both have the same output. As such there is a race between them and which "wins" cannot be determined in advance.

As Luiggi Mendoza says;

> In order to get the desired result, OP just have to change
>   System.out.print to System.error.print or catch the Error and print it
>   using e.printStacktrace(System.out). Or even better, use a logger that
>   handles all this work for you

It is additionally worth noting that your catch statement does not catch this `new Error()` because `Error`!=`Exception`

Comment: +1 for the awesomeness in the answer

Comment: In order to *get* the desired result, OP just have to change `System.out.print` to `System.error.print` or catch the `Error` and print it using `e.printStacktrace(System.out)`. Or even better, use a logger that handles all this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    catch (Exception ex)
```

into

```
    catch (Throwable ex)
```

which catches more (Throwable being the base class). It also catches the stack trace in badMethod, which probably does `e.printStacktrace()`, which calls `e.printStacktrace(System.err)`. `Exception` is for checked Exception, not RuntimeExceptions.

To the console both writers (PrintStreams), System.out and System.err are written simultaneous, in different threads: so really mixed up.

Comment: I know Throwable can be used, but @Richard answered what I was looking for. Although your answer also provides good info. +1:)

Comment: Thanks, he was first. I just wanted to point out about Throwable; in some verbosity as the question+answer might be sought in the future by others.

Comment: Part about different threads is wrong, though; separate buffers, same thread.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill so repeated runs should cause the same garbled console under the same condition? Thanks.

Comment: The indeterminate behavior comes from the OS; if the Java program doesn't flush the buffers, it's up to the OS as to when the data is pulled from each of the buffers and displayed.